# Is it wrong to use deprecated method in objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, deprecated

Today i compile my application with 10.7 SDK and i am getting warnings for deprecated methods.
Should i change all deprecated methods?
Is it wrong to use deprecated method in objective c?

Comment: The deprecated methods may well be removed in the 10.8 SDK, often one major version is all that Apple will give you to update your code. If it's little-to-no effort to use modern APIs, you ought to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, You should change deprecated methods because they may go away in the future.

> In computer software standards and documentation, the term deprecation
>   is used to indicate discouragement of usage of a particular software
>   feature, usually because it has been superseded by a newer/better
>   version. The deprecated feature still works in the current version of
>   the software, but it may raise error messages or warnings.

[Wiki: about Deprecation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation).

Comment: @SIGSEGV I don't think that it will create very noticeable performance issue. It's everything about supporting it in the future, because one day it can be removed.

Comment: Does Apple do the same. Sometime you have to do which is not encouraged but you have only solution.